# mysql dump tables only

Tags: mysql, export

In my database I have some tables and views. 
How can I export all the tables (and not the views) from my database from command line?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use mysqldump with the option [--ignore-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) to exclude the views individually. Or use mysqldump and remove the views with an application/manually. grep might be an option:

```
grep -v "CREATE VIEW" db.dump > db-without-views.dump
```

Comment: Beware that the dumper writes multiple lines per view, so excluding the mentioned first line only will leave errors in your dump.

Comment: What @ZsoltSzilagy said.  --ignore-tables works, but the rest will result in a broken export.

Answer (score 31):

To ignore a single view from your DB for Dump:

```
mysqldump -uusrname -ppwd -h hostname --ignore-table=db.view_name db > db.sql
```

To ignore multiple view from your Db for Dump:

```
mysqldump -uusrname -ppwd -h hostname --ignore-table=db.view1 --ignore-table=db.view2 db > db.sql
```

NOTE: to ignore multiple views for dump use `--ignore-table` option multiple times.

Answer (score 29):

The current implementation mysqldump won't create dumps without views -- and furthermore, (last time I checked) views are actually created twice -- once as a table, then the table is dropped and replaced with a view. So you can't just filter out the "CREATE VIEW" command, unless that behavior has been modified.

However, mysqldump will take a list of tables as parameters following the database name. Something like this:

```
mysqldump -ujoe -pmysecret joesdb posts tags comments users
```

Comment: You can even query the tables from MySQL's information schema: `mysqldump the_db_i_want $(mysql -Ne"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='the_db_i_want' AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'")`

Answer (score 9):

Backuping a single table from a database

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASWORD DATABASE TABLE_NAME --host=HOST_NAME > c:\TABLE_NAME.sql
```

Restoring a single table from a database dump

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE --host=HOST_NAME < c:\TABLE_NAME.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated @ladieu's script:

- Shell arguments are properly escaped permitting passwords with shell caracters
- Using PDO instead of mysql specific functions (sometime an IP seems to be resolved against DNS with the mysql_* functions and thus trigger an error)
- Removed assumption that the script is used locally (added host parameter)
- Using the "-r" options to avoid encoding issues
- name the output file .sql
- rearranged parameters so it does fit in "I want to connect to  with user  identified by  and dump  database>

```php
<?php

if (is_array($argv) && count($argv)>3) {
    $host=($argv[1]);
    $user=($argv[2]);
    $password=($argv[3]);
    $database=($argv[4]);

}
else {
    echo "Usage php mysqdump.php <host> <user> <password> <database>\n";
    exit;
}

echo 'connecting to'.$host;

$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$user,$password);

//$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

//$source = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
$sql = "SHOW FULL TABLES IN `$database` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$views=array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   $views[]="--ignore-table={$database}.".$row[0];
}
//no views or triggers please
$host=escapeshellarg($host);
$user=escapeshellarg($user);
$password=escapeshellarg($password);
$database=escapeshellarg($database);
echo passthru("mysqldump -h $host -u $user --password=\"$password\" $database --skip-triggers ".implode(" ",$views)." -r $database.sql");
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Usage

```
php mysqldump.php mydatabase myusername mypassword > myoutputfile.sql
```

This is a pretty old script of mine. Someone could easily adapt this to use PDO if you do not have access to the mysql functions.

```
<?php

if (is_array($argv) && count($argv)>3) {
    $database=$argv[1];
    $user=$argv[2];
    $password=$argv[3];
}
else {
    echo "Usage php mysqdump.php <database> <user> <password>\n";
    exit;
}

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $password);


if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$source = mysql_select_db('$database', $link);
$sql = "SHOW FULL TABLES IN `$database` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$views=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $views[]="--ignore-table={$database}.".$row[0];
}
//no views or triggers please
echo passthru("mysqldump -u root --password=\"$password\" $database --skip-triggers ".implode(" ",$views));

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
mysqldump -h drupdbsvr  -u elt_drupal_dba -pdrupdev-654! clms_admin views_display views_view view_argument view_exposed_filter view_filter view_sort view_tablefield view_view > /opt/dbdump/clms_admin_view.sql
```

Where the syntax is:-

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u database_user_name database_password database_name table_name1 table_name2 > path/sql_file.sql
```